# Create dynamic URL and Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I page some customer profiles and I'd like that their profiles pages URL's be their names.

For example, someone called John Doe, would have a profile:

```
mydomain.com/profiles/johndoe
```

If there are more the one John Doe, so I'd like to let:

```
mydomain.com/profiles/johndoe1

mydomain.com/profiles/johndoe2
```

I've read about dynamic route here

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

But I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With wild cards in the url you can accomplish your task.  In `config/routes.rb` put:

```
get '/profiles/:username', to: 'controller_name#action_name'
```

Now `params[:username]` is equal to "johndoe1" in your first example and "johndoe2" your second url example.  So you can in your controller, put

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
end
```

and it will populate @user with the database record based on username.

Note: Obviously, I'm making some pretty big assumptions about your setup, so you are going to have to tweek things here and there for your own personal case, but this should give you a general idea.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!
Actually, I didn't have this field username, only first_name and last_name, but I created a new field username like you suggested.